# Change UITableView Cell Color

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (self.from! == "Hello") {
            println("Hello")
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        } else {
            println("Not Hello")
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }
    }
```

The issue is it's applying to entire table - I just want to change the last cell created.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the data source for your table? An array?

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine how many rows are in your table and apply the color change to just that row.  I see that you are trying to change the color in willdisplaycell.  You can do this when you create the cell if you'd like.  I assume you are using reusable cells.  You know how many rows are in your section because this is set in

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
         return myData.count 
    }
```

Then when creating the cell :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell") as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = myData[indexPath.row]
    if (indexPath.row == myData.count-1) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change contentView color

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` also good for it

Comment: Thanks - can I also use to change cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor() for current cell. ContentView doesn't work with textColor :(

Comment: labels you could change with cell.label etc...... but background it's conteView property. If you'd like to change last cell take last indexPath index of your tableview. But be aware if your tableview is reusable, last cell will always change

Comment: I added cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() to willDisplayCell func but it is still updating the entire table not just one single cell.

Comment: you should write Indexpath condition. or something like this: if (cell.label.text == "hello") { cell.contentview.backgroundcolor = UIColor.yellowColor() }